# Text field clears when editing a form

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

When I edit a resource and click on the text field in the form - the old value disappears.
it happens across multiple forms
What can cause this behavior ?
is it a rails issue or js ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possibly a javascript issue - do you have a script that sets any fields deliberate to blank (like a search box, or similar)?
If so, you may have an error in it which is blanking *all* text boxes.

Turn off JS in your browser and try it...